# Using <select> tag to update database in PHP with a submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to find ways how to update my database for hours now and it's hurting my brain.

Please, can anyone show me how to update data inside a database by using `<select>`?

If I select 'Checked-Out' in the form and then click update the StatusID in the database will be updated to '2' but I just can't seem to work it.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $_var1 = $_POST['status'];

    $query3 = mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET ReservationStatusID = '$_var1' WHERE  `ReservationID` = '$id' ");


        if($query3)
        {
            header('location:viewReservedroomsGuest1.php');

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error";
        }

}
?>
```

Here's my select.

```
<select  id="status">
  <option  value="1">Checked-In</option>
  <option  value="2">Checked-Out</option>
  <option  value="3">Pending</option>
  <option  value="4">Cancelled</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
```

I'm sorry, I don't make any sense. My brain is tired out already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <form action="sampleupdate.php" method="post">
       <select  id="status" name="status">
          <option  value="1">Checked-In</option>
          <option  value="2">Checked-Out</option>
          <option  value="3">Pending</option>
          <option  value="4">Cancelled</option>
        </select>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
```

in sampleupdate.php

```
$val = $_POST['status'];
```

// and write and execute the update Query here..

Comment: Thanks! It works. IT WORKS. I created a new .php but it didn't work so I tried inserting the <?php code here ?> inside the  page itself and that did the trick. Once again, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Put the select in a `<form>` with `method="post"`
- Give the select a `name` attribute
- Read the data from `$_POST['the name you used']`
- Use [the database API](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) of your choice

Comment: Thanks for making it easy to understand >:3